# Fetch google calendar events from php

Tags: php

I've been playing with the samples from this site: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/calendar/v3/using.html

All I want to do fetch the cal data from a public calendar. But so far there's always something that makes me hit a wall. I'm doing a webapp but it always pointing to a specific calendar that is public. I don't need to use oauth. only the api key. But I really can't find any samples of doing this.

Any hint to get me in the right direction. I don't even know what to try after trying the samples on that page.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: I found this http://james.cridland.net/code/google-calendar.html which will get me started from another point I think. I looks like it will work. Thanks anyway! I get back here if it don't work...

Answer (score 1):

see actually how it processed using oauth here.
https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/
you can get step to implement this.

you have to use

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}